# Magento 2 Change default store view in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, store-switcher

Can Anyone know how to set a default store view in admin?

[image]

Please let me know if anyone have any idea about this.

Comment: Please Can you explain more , you have many stores?

Comment: Whenever I edit/add any product then by default I need to show the US select in-store view.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

In the Admin panel, click `Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web`.
From the Store View list at the top of the page, click Default Config.

In the right pane, expand Base URLs.
In the Base URLs section, clear Use system value.

And Last Click Save Config.